# 80's-90's young adult horror story help!

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, young-adult, horror

This is a collection of short stories I have been looking for a long time.

One story involved two children that discovered tunnels, either in their back yard or the woods that we underground and had little monsters in them. 
Specifically the story I remember best involved a boy needing to blend in with the monsters, or he becomes invested in some way with them and wants to be a part of them. They may be all stitched together parts. His (the kid's) grandfather had some involvement with the monsters and the kid finds a stitched together skin suit made of the monsters in his grandfathers things. He wears it and becomes one of them... That or he ends up giving his body parts to them and dies in the end.

This was in a collection of scary stories I used to check out from the public library.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/214189/ya-book-about-blind-creatures-that-live-underground-and-take-kids-eyes (which is newer but has an OP-provided answer)

Answer (score 4):

It was not a short story, but the plot details you refer to sound very similar to William Sleator's *[The Beasties](http://www.publishersweekly.com/978-0-525-45598-1)*.

The plot description is as follows:

> Sleator's (The Spirit House) latest novel revolves around a community of small, pasty creatures that live underground and harvest the humans who inhabit the surface. The Beasties have been deprived of their forest home and of various crucial body parts by commercial loggers. They replace their losses with human limbs, which they amputate from the human host, using crude surgical techniques. When teenage Doug, the narrator, and his little sister Colette move to a deserted house in the country, the Beasties coerce the pair into helping them maim a logger.

There is also a mention of character traits:

> Doug is an athlete, Colette is a bookworm

And some spoilerific information that may nonetheless jog your memory, in regards to your comment of **"They may be all stitched together parts."**

> Doug even donates one of his eyes to the creatures' new leader, who is blind.

Many reviewers pinpointed the book as being ["memorable"](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/The_Beasties.html?id=COTNAQAACAAJ&redir_esc=y), so it's quite possibly the one you were looking for. Hope this helps!

Comment: Which plot details? Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Gallifreyan based on further research, it certainly appears to be the actual book